# SLF4J Defaulting to Log4j over logback even when binding doesn't exist

Tags: java, logging, log4j, slf4j, logback

I am trying to get SLF4J to bind to logback, but it is instead defaulting to Log4j.

I have all the default config files configured for logback, as well as the bindings.

My classpath has the following relevant jars:

logback-classic
commons-logging (99.0-does-not-exist) //empty jar to exclude commons-logging
logback-core
logback-ext-spring

Note: No *log4j* dependencies are present.

This is a spring mvc app.

On startup SLF4J has the following output:

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/masierp/Documents/springsource/vfabric-tc-server-developer-2.8.2.RELEASE/blablahbkla/wtpwebapps/ilm-engine/WEB-INF/lib/activemq-all-5.7.0.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/masierp/Documents/springsource/vfabric-tc-server-developer-2.8.2.RELEASE/blablahbkla/wtpwebapps/ilm-engine/WEB-INF/lib/logback-classic-1.1.2.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
```

Note that none of the found bindings are log4j bindings.

I have messed with spring-ext (trying to use it as the spring listener) but with or without this jar the problem persists.

Any help appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Probably one of your dependencies has a log4j dependency. You need to exclude it.
Try to look on the parent pom.

Comment: mvn dependency:tree | grep "log4j" returns nothing. I have removed every log4j dependency there is.

Comment: And are you sure there is no JAR inside the project that maybe wrapped with Log4j accidentally?